# How to change the color of the selected value of Select Field in sencha?

Tags: css, sencha-touch-2

How to change the color of the selected value of Select Field in sencha? It appears grey by default.

```
                {

                    xtype: 'selectfield',
                    ui: 'text',
                    value : 12,
                    cls:'b',
                    style: {
                        'font-size':'12px',
                    },
                    options: belts
                },
```

and in my app.scss i have:

```
.b
{
color:black !important;
 }
```

I have also tried:

```
                {

                    xtype: 'selectfield',
                    ui: 'text',
                    value : 12,
                    cls:'b',
                    style:  'font-size:12px;color:black',
                    options: belts
                },
```

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Just use their forum you will get better answer with explanation http://www.sencha.com/forum/forumdisplay.php?89-Sencha-Touch-2.x-Forums

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually wanted the text to appear in black. Changing

```
ui:'text'
```

to

```
ui:'plain'
```

helped me solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this way :-

```
{
  xtype: 'selectfield',
  label: 'Choose one',
  inputCls:'selecttext',
  options: [
             {text: 'First Option',  value: 'first'},
             {text: 'Second Option', value: 'second'},
             {text: 'Third Option',  value: 'third'}
           ]
}
```

In css make class

```
.selecttext{
   color: #f25454 !important;
   -webkit-text-fill-color:#f25454 !important;
   background-color: #2d2d2d;
}
```